# How to bundle and copy CSS files from source folder to dist folder?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

I want to minify and bundle the CSS files inside my `src/css` folder and output it as a single CSS file inside `dist`. All the examples I've seen so far recommend `require`-ing the CSS file inside a JS file. I do not want that. Is there a way to configure in `webpack.config.js` to just minify and copy these files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it working.

Install dev-dependecies

```
npm i extract-text-webpack-plugin --save-dev
npm i css-loader --save-dev
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.min.css')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bundle.min.css': [
      __dirname + '/src/styles/abc.css',
      __dirname + '/src/styles/xyz.css',
      __dirname + '/src/styles/mno.css'
    ]
  },
  devtool: '',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/styles/',
    filename: '[name]'

  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: extractCSS.extract({
          use: {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        })
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {},
    modules: [],
    extensions: ['.css']
  },
  plugins: [
    extractCSS
  ]
};
```

`bundle.min.css` will get generated. Based on `minimize: true/false`, minification will be decided. Enjoy!

Comment: Is it necessary to specify all css files in the entry?

Comment: Yea, because one css file won't include another. So one has to write it manually. In case of JS files, one entry point is needed and all other js files which are imported are automatically gets bundled. Visualize the graph of the imported statements and you will understand.

Comment: extract-text-webpack-plugin is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

It will go in three steps;

first you will need two loaders and plugin; named `css-loader` and `style-loader` and `extract-text-webpack-plugin` respectively.

Then your config might look like following:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: 'dist',
    filename: 'js/[name]-bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: "cheap-source-map",
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules'),
    ]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.css?$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' }),
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name].css"),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        conditionals: true,
        unused: true,
        comparisons: true,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        evaluate: true,
        join_vars: true,
        if_return: true
      },
      output: {
        comments: false
      }
    }),
  ]
}
```

And then in your entry file, require them like `require('./style.css');`

Remember, it will follow the paths as your source.

If you are loading font files and images in you css, you might need the `file-loader` plugin as well which will copy all assets in directory.

The file-loader config will look like:

```
{
    test: /.png?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]',
    exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

The `UgligyJsPlugin` will also minify the CSS.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without `require`-ing the CSS from JS file? That feels very odd.

Comment: CSS would not be added in JS file, it is just a require, which means that JS app depends on CSS files. This config is straight form one of my applications.